# Piping to ForEach-Object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, foreach, pipe

I'm trying to get it to recurse through a directory, and include only `.pdf` files. Then return the 3 most recently modified `.pdf`'s, and stick each of their (full) filenames into their respective variables.

Here's my code so far -

```
$Directory="C:\PDFs"
Get-ChildItem -path $Directory -recurse -include *.pdf | sort-object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | select-object -First 3 | ForEach-Object 
    {
        Write-Host -FilePath $_.fullname
    }
```

However, when I run the script, it asks me to provide parameters for the ForEach portion of the script - Which leaves me to conclude that either the command isn't piping the way it should, or the command isn't being using the command properly.

Comment: FYI mods this page is a top google hit, and it solved my problem.  I cannot imagine what is too localized about this issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `enter` after the `foreach-object`:

```
$Directory="C:\PDFs"
Get-ChildItem -path $Directory -recurse -include *.pdf | sort-object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | select-object -First 3 | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host -FilePath $_.fullname   }
```

There's a typo in your code:

```
**    Get-ChildItem =path  **
```

Answer (score 5):

It's probably because your script block for the ForEach-Object is on a new line. In PowerShell you need to use the backtick character (`) to tell PowerShell a command continues to the next line. Try this:

```
$Directory="C:\PDFs"
    Get-ChildItem -path $Directory -recurse -include *.pdf | sort-object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | select-object -First 3 | ForEach-Object `
    {
        Write-Host -FilePath $_.fullname
    }
```